# Calling Action Class on click of button

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

How do i call an action class when a button on a jsp is clicked?. I am using `struts 1.3` framework

Below is the code snippet:

```
<html:button property="delete" onclick="/deleteZeroScoreCard.do" value="Delete"></html:button>
```

`"/deleteZeroScoreCard"` is defined in `struts-config.xml` file

I am getting below compile error

```
Syntax error on token "Non Terminating Regular Expression", no accurate correction available
```

Edit:

`Struts-config.xml` snippet

```
   <form-bean name="initiationfrm" type="com.mindcraft.mis.zero.actionform.afInitiation"></form-bean>

    <action name="initiationfrm" path="/deleteZeroScoreCard" type="com.mindcraft.mis.zero.actionclass.acZeroScoreCardDeletion">
        <forward name="viewdatauploaddppage2" path="zeroInitPage"></forward>

    </action>
```

Comment: This looks like a message of your IDE. What does happen when you really execute this in your web container?

Comment: I get error on page Expected "/"

Comment: please drop your code from struts-config.xml for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onclick attribute will run JavaScript, and "/deleteZeroScoreCard.do" is not valid JavaScript. You'll need something like onclick="location.href='/deleteZeroScoreCard.do';" instead.

Why don't you avoid JavaScript and instead use a form? For example:

```
<html:form action="deleteZeroScoreCard" method="POST">
    <html:button property="delete" value="Delete"/>
</html:form>
```